# Unity: UI Image alpha overlap

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Problem:** Two objects in canvas blend with each other when CanvasGroup modifies their transparency.

Example in the picture: the scene has a dark background, the canvas has green and red images. If the opacity of both objects is less then 100%, they will blend.

Left: opacity is 100%;

Center: opacity is 50%, images blend (actual result);

Right: opacity is 50%, images don't blend (desired result)

[image]

How to prevent blending of the images based on their order? I am aware of a texture-based solution (the second camera renders to a texture which is placed in canvas), but it seems like such overkill. Is there any other approach? Shaders, changes via code, something else?

Unity 2019.3.0f1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Resolution:** a new shader and its material, plus one additional material. *Shader creation can be avoided in some situations!*

Shaders in Unity has a tool called Stencil. This tool maintains pixel buffer that can be used to discard pixels.

**CanvasImageMask shader:** it is a clone of default UI image shader, except Stencil adjustments and tiny addition for comfort work. When mask rendering is happening, Stencil will set the pixel buffer's value to 1 in the place where it actually drew something. The second shader reacts to this change and discards new pixels in that location. Keep in mind that objects with such material (that hold CanvasImageMask shader) should come first in Canvas because during rendering they will modify pixel buffers, which can be used later.

All objects that should be masked have to use another material that is based on default UI image shader with Stencil adjustments. This material will discard any pixels with a buffer's value equal or higher than 1.

Note that this work can be avoided. The developer can create 2 materials (clones of default image material), and modify Stencil settings in the editor. But this solution has a problem: how to create such a mask, that shouldn't be drawn? The best solution would be alpha channels set to 1 (out of 255). But if Canvas is using CanvasGroup, pixels can be discarded earlier, and the mask won't work.

CanvasImageMask shader hides Stencil settings (convenience) and adds a flag, which will hide all pixels from the mask yet still do the job.

**CanvasImageMask:**

```
Shader "Custom/CanvasImageMask"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [MaterialToggle(DO_NOT_DRAW)]
        _DoNotDraw ("Do not draw", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        { 
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Stencil
        {
            Ref 1
            Comp Greater
            Pass Replace
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest [unity_GUIZTestMode]
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask RGBA

        Pass
        {
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma shader_feature DO_NOT_DRAW
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
#ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
                OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw-1.0)*float2(-1,1);
#endif
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                clip (color.a - 0.01);
                #ifdef DO_NOT_DRAW
                    color.a = 0;
                #endif
                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to compare, here is the default UI image shader:

```
Shader "UI/Default"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

        _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

        _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        { 
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Stencil
        {
            Ref [_Stencil]
            Comp [_StencilComp]
            Pass [_StencilOp] 
            ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest [unity_GUIZTestMode]
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask [_ColorMask]

        Pass
        {
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
#ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
                OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw-1.0)*float2(-1,1);
#endif
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                clip (color.a - 0.01);
                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

---

To summarize: create CanvasImageMask, create material based on this shader, and place an image on the canvas. Create another material, based on default shader, set Stencil ID to 1, and Stencil comparison to 5 (aka "Greater"). Assign this material to any other image on the canvas that comes after mask object.

**References:**

- [Stencil tool in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html)
- [Source of Default UI image shader (read the desc)](https://youtu.be/l7LQmJuoiBY)
- [Soft mask in UI.](https://github.com/mob-sakai/SoftMaskForUGUI) Didn't resolve my problem, but it was a somewhat decent reference.

Comment: It works nicely, but what about nested images, I've got a few images inside a container image parent, and everything below just pop over the parent afeter apply this materials.

Comment: @LobsangWhite, please be more specific. What order do you expect, what images should be masked? For example, here is what I did: [root]->[root's child 1 = invisible mask]->[root's child 2 = image to be masked]->[any other child of root]. This works, because in canvas order matters. For example, some nesting works as well: [root]->[root's child 1 = invisible mask]->[mask's child1 = object to be masked]->[any other child of root]. The second example works just as well because the order in canvas is the same: root, child 1 (all children of child 1), child 2 (all children of child 2), child 3, etc

Comment: I'm going to try that order, however Imagine a sandwich where the cheese is a progress bar between the progress bar container and the icon who makes reference at the top of everything, normally everything like that looks awful when the alpha is modified using canvas group, just like the problem described here.

Comment: @LobsangWhite sandwich analogy sheds a better light on your situation. So in your example parenting doesn't play any role. The drawing order does. Does the container have an image? If so, then the order is following: mask with progress bar's shape (stencil id=1), mask with icon's shape (stencil id=1), container (maskable, with stencil id = 1), mask with icon's shape (id 2), the progress bar (maskable, with stencil id = 2), icon (default material/shader). Masks with id=1 will cut the container's image where progress bar & icon are and mask with id=2 will cut progress bar behind your icon.

Comment: @LobsangWhite I also have a progress bar and an icon on top of it. However, my icon is placed on the side of the bar, not in the middle. So I use only 1 mask to cut everything (progress bar and bar's background) except the icon itself. And I am avoiding containers with images in the root. It complicates development or maintenance for me.